# How to implement undo in Spring REST API

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, asynchronous, undo

I need some ideas on how to implement a simple undo function.  Its a Spring web-app with JS frontend and the typical Spring REST API.  The undo feature should work very similar to the undo in Google Keep, e.g.  User clicks delete, UI appears to delete object, small popup appears in corner with undo link for approximately 10 sec, after which it disappears and undo is no longer available.

My initial thoughts were to use an async message queue.  Perhaps a commandQueue and an undoCommandQueue.  When a message enters the commandQueue it is delayed for 10sec. After the delay a service activator recieves the message and checks to see if there is a corresponding undo message in the undoCommandQueue with matching Id, if not then it proceeds with the delete.

If possible(and not significantly more complicated) I'd like to avoid using a msg queue.  Perhaps something like an async delete method that has a 10 sec sleep built in. But then how do I notify this async method after it's done sleeping that a completely separate undo REST API call was made?

I know the command pattern is the de-facto approach for undo, but given that I only want 1 level of undo for a very short amount of time that seems like overkill.  The simplest solution would likely be to delay the delete API call altogether using javascript on the frontend, but that is an issue in some scenarios like immediately closing the browser(so the API never gets called).

Anyone done anything like this before? Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: <sigh>... no answers...  For the sake of anyone who runs across this post here are the possibly viable solutions i've come up with: 1)handle it on the frontend, essentially create an API call that re-adds the deleted data.  2) Delay the initial delete call using something like a msg queue 3)use a command pattern in the api.  This is the traditional approach, clearly the most comprehensive(allows multiple levels of undo), but also is time-consuming to implement especially if you are working with an existing api.